# How to control focussed option while options change order with react-select

Tags: react-select

I'm using a search feature which reorders the options as you type. React-select maintains the focus of what was originally the first option, even if that option then moves to a different place in the list. So when you type the focus jumps up and down the screen. I'd like the focussed option to stay as the first option while typing.

Is there any way to control which option is focussed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a randomly generated "value" property to the options passed into react-select seems to create the functionality I was looking for.

```
// code for loadOptions prop in react-select's AsyncCreatable
import uniq from "uniqid";

// code to get search results

const resultsWithRandomValue = results.map(r => ({ ...r.item, value: uniq() }));
```

It's not ideal, but anything else would need changes to `react-select`, and I'm not sure how much need there is for this behaviour in general.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to edit some code example ?